# Запись в файл координат из 4 numpy массивов

Tags: python, файлы, numpy

Есть 4 numpy массива с координатами x,y и скоростями u,v:

```
 Xg [[-0.5  0.3  1.1]
     [-0.5  0.3  1.1]
     [-0.5  0.3  1.1]]

  Yg [[-0.5 -0.5 -0.5]
     [ 0.3  0.3  0.3]
     [ 1.1  1.1  1.1]]

  u [[ 1.  1.  1.]
     [ 1.  1.  1.]
     [ 1.  1.  1.]]

v [[ 1.03793  0.25065 -0.28944]
   [-0.21591 -0.93072 -0.10047]
   [-0.08591 -0.11284 -0.06082]]
```

Как записать в файл попарно координаты, чтобы это выглядело следующим образом:

```
 # в файле должно быть ", {{" x_координата","y_координата"},
  {"u_координата","v_координата"}}")
file = open("coordinates.txt", "w")
file.write(",{{" + x + "," + y + "},{" + u + "," + v + "}}")

 #Output
 ,{{-0.5,-0.5},{1,1.03793}}, {{0.3,-0.5},{1,0.25065}}, {{1.1,-0.5},{1,-0.28944}},...
```

Comment: Для чего вы хотите сохранить массивы в файл? Если для того, чтобы потом снова использовать в python, то советую использовать [pickle](https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-pickle.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
', '.join(['{{%s,%s}, {%s,%s}}' %(x,y,u,v)
           for x,y,u,v in np.column_stack(map(np.ravel, (Xg, Yg, u, v)))])
```

Результат:

```
In [27]: pprint.pprint(s)
('{{-0.5,-0.5}, {1.0,1.03793}}, {{0.3,-0.5}, {1.0,0.25065}}, {{1.1,-0.5}, '
 '{1.0,-0.28944}}, {{-0.5,0.3}, {1.0,-0.21591}}, {{0.3,0.3}, {1.0,-0.93072}}, '
 '{{1.1,0.3}, {1.0,-0.10047}}, {{-0.5,1.1}, {1.0,-0.08591}}, {{0.3,1.1}, '
 '{1.0,-0.11284}}, {{1.1,1.1}, {1.0,-0.06082}}')
```

> А как можно сделать, чтобы в файл не записывались значения типа
>   `-2.22044604925e-16`, чтобы они были 0

Воспользуйтесь [numpy.set_printoptions()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html):

```
In [1]: a = np.array([1.23456789, -2.22044604925e-16])

In [2]: a
Out[2]: array([  1.23456789e+00,  -2.22044605e-16])

In [3]: print(a)
[  1.23456789e+00  -2.22044605e-16]

In [4]: np.set_printoptions(precision=4, suppress=True)

In [5]: print(a)
[ 1.2346 -0.    ]
```

Comment: А как можно сделать, чтобы в файл не записывались значения типа -2.22044604925 e - 16, чтобы они были 0.

Comment: куда вставлять  numpy.set_printoptions() ?

Comment: @AleksandrAleksandrov, перед выводом в файл